# Can react-toolbox be rendered from the serverside from a isomorphic/universal app?

Tags: reactjs, isomorphic-javascript, react-toolbox

http://react-toolbox.com/ Looks really good, but they have a sass dependency. Is there a way to use react-toolbox in a isomorphic/universal app and render them from the server, or are the sass dependencies somehow declared within the components?

They recommend using a CSS loader in the webpack development build. This leads me to the conclusion that the CSS dependencies are within the React Components. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be rendered on the server side.

A preferred way is to utilize Webpack build with css-loader and sass-loader. Take a look on [webpack-isomorphic-tools](https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/webpack-isomorphic-tools) as an example of the plugin which could help with a server-side rendering of the react apps.

In my current project, we are using a forked version of [webpack-starter-kit](https://github.com/webpack/react-starter). Both examples allow you to utilize react-toolbox for a universal app. I am sure you could find at least a dozen of similar setups on GitHub.